# Including block content between templates

Tags: javascript, symfony, styles, twig, block

I have a big problem with including blocks between templates. The code is following:

```
{# layout.html.twig #} (simplified version)
<html>
<head>
.....
.....
{% block stylesheets%}{% endblock %}
{% block javascripts %}{% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
{% block content %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>

{# index.html.twig #}
{% extends "demoBundle::layout.html.twig" %}
{% block content %}
some content           {# <---- this is working #}
{% render(controller('demoBundle:Default:renderIndexContent')) %}
{% endblock %}

{# DefaultController.php #}
...
...
return $this->render('demoBundle:Gallery:slideshow.html.twig');
...
...

{# slideshow.html.twig #}
{% block stylesheet %}   {# <---- this is not working #}
<link rel="stylesheets" href="{{ asset('bundles/cms/css/pictureSlider.css') }}"/>
{% endblock %}
```

The idea is, index.html.twig extends layout, and rendering another template with name slideshow.html.twig trought controller. But I need include stylesheets inner block in the template slideshow.html.twig to stylesheets block in head position in the main template layout.html.twig, but does not work. When i add tag {{ parent() }} to the block stylesheet in the template slideshow.html.twig, symfony say

*Calling "parent" on a template that does not extend nor "use" another template is forbidden in demoBundle:Gallery:slideshow.html.twig at line 3*

/***EDITED****/

No, it is not resolution for me, because i have some variables returnet from defaultcontroller.php in template index.html.twig.

Ok, the previous code was just a simpliefed example.  I enclose a concrete example

**index.html.twig**
    {% extends "cmsBundle::layout.html.twig" %}

```
{% block rightSideBar %}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="top_block">
      <div id="module-1" class="no-title">
          {% for block in blocksCenter %}
            {% if (block.position=="center-top") %}
                {% render(controller('cmsBundle:Default:renderIndexBlocks',{'blockname':block.name})) %}
            {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
      </div>

...
```

block.name is for example "slideshow". In the DefaultController.php inner method renderIndexBlocksAction is this piece of code:

**DefaultController.php**

```
return $this->render(
                'cmsBundle:Blocks:'.$blockname.'.html.twig'
                ,array('items'=>$items)
                );
```

this render template name slideshow.html.twig, there is this piece of code:

**slideshow.html.twig**

```
{% block styles %}
{{ parent() }}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/cms/css/pictureSlider.css') }}" type="text/css" media="all"/>

{% endblock %}
{% block javascripts %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('bundles/cms/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js') }}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

for completenes, her is the piece of layout.html.twig

**layout.html.twig**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ asset('bundles/cms/images/favicon.ico') }}" type="image/x-icon" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="robots" content="index, follow" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/cms/css/style.css') }}" type="text/css" media="all"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/cms/css/menu.css') }}" type="text/css" media="all"/>
    {% block styles %}{% endblock %}
    {% block javascripts %}{% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
    <div id="bg_image"><img src="{{ asset('bundles/cms/images/AbstractBlue.jpg') }}" alt="" style="width:100%; height:100%;"></div>
    <div id="mainContainer">
        <div id="header">
            <div id="top1">
                <div id="logo">
                    <div id="search">
                        {% include 'cmsBundle:Default:search.html.twig' %}
                    </div>
                    <div class="wrapper" style="width:987px"/>
                            <div id="menu" class="menu">
                                {% render(controller('cmsBundle:Default:renderMenu')) %}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>

        <div id="blocks" class="blocks">{% block rightSideBar %}{% endblock %}</div>

        <!--CONTENT-->
            <div id="mainContentm">
                {% block content %}{% endblock %}
            </div><!-- end #content -->

            <!-- #footer -->
            <div id="footer">
                <div id="footer-left">
                </div>

                <div id="footer-right">
                </div>
            </div><!-- end #footer -->

    </div><!-- end #container -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have shown you the way to properly extend the templates without extending them you will not be able to access their blocks like if there is `{% block styles %}` defined previously then you can call parent in child templates if child templates extend them

Comment: Ugh, so when I have such a following structure:

layout -> index -> slideshow

so I can access block in layout from index, but do not from slideshow because index extend layout, but slideshow do not extend any parent template?

Comment: For your structure what i understand you are including block only so if there is a slide show block then you should add the stylesheet file in the style block of `layout.html.twig or in index.html.twig` or other way just include the stylesheet file in your block html

Comment: hmm, so the solution is that i call stylesheet without block in slideshow.html.twig ? but after i will stylesheet definition in body section, and do not in head section... it is not so good.

Comment: My idea is, that i dynamically load some blocks like slideshow etc., but I dont want include all stylesheets or javascripts in layout.html.twig (but  i want dynamically load these files)

Maybe solution would be use a "use" macro, but i dont know how i use "use" with bundled controller...

Comment: including css files and js files in their blocks within a head section its a good practice symfony makes a cache for these files so first load is harder after clearing cache but once cache is built all css nd js files are read from cache so it will not be a big issue regarding performance to load all files in head tag

Comment: ok, i try this solution. Thank you for your kind help with this issue.

Answer (score 1):

The error itself says calling parent on a template that does not extend nor use means your template `slideshow.html.twig` is not extending any parent template or  layout to follow thus if there is not parent template you cannot call the stylesheets of member that does not exist,for answer to your question in `slideshow.html.twig` use

```
{% extends '::index.html.twig' %}
```

and then define

```
{% block stylesheets %}
{{ parent() }}
<link rel="stylesheets" href="{{ asset('bundles/cms/css/pictureSlider.css') }}"/>
{% endblock %}
```

If there are any stylesheets in `index.html.twig` these will be included in your template,as viewing the `index.html.twig` code there is empty `stylesheets` block.If `layout.html.twig` has also defined a block for stylesheets then you should call `{{ parent() }}` function in the stylesheets block of `index.html.twig` so it will include the stylesheets of its parent layout i.e `layout.html.twig`